# mingw32-make following cmake with "MinGW Makefiles" generator fails to link executable to object library

Tags: c++, windows, makefile, cmake, mingw

I'm using CMake to facilitate cross-platform builds of a C++ project. Using the same CMakeLists.txt files, I'm successfully completing builds on Linux (generating Unix Makefiles to compile with g++), OSX (generating Unix Makefiles to compile with clang++), and Windows (generating for Visual Studio 16 2019).

Most recently, I've been testing the build process using the MinGW Makefiles generator on Windows. CMake generates the Makefile without any problems. When I call `mingw32-make` in the directory where the Makefile is generated, however, I start to run into problems. I'm able to compile several source files into an object library, but when I try to link the print_graphs executable to this object library, I get a flood of `multiple definition` errors for methods in the first source file of the object library, as follows:

```
Scanning dependencies of target print_graphs
[ 52%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/print_graphs.dir/print_graphs.cpp.obj
[ 57%] Linking CXX executable print_graphs.exe
CMakeFiles\print_graphs.dir/objects.a(roaring.c.obj):roaring.c:(.text+0x6833): multiple definition of `roaring_bitmap_get_copy_on_write'
CMakeFiles\print_graphs.dir/objects.a(print_graphs.cpp.obj):print_graphs.cpp:(.text$roaring_bitmap_get_copy_on_write[roaring_bitmap_get_copy_on_write]+0x0): first defined here
CMakeFiles\print_graphs.dir/objects.a(roaring.c.obj):roaring.c:(.text+0x6850): multiple definition of `roaring_bitmap_set_copy_on_write'
CMakeFiles\print_graphs.dir/objects.a(print_graphs.cpp.obj):print_graphs.cpp:(.text$roaring_bitmap_set_copy_on_write[roaring_bitmap_set_copy_on_write]+0x0): first defined here
CMakeFiles\print_graphs.dir/objects.a(set_cover_solver.cpp.obj):set_cover_solver.cpp:(.text$ra_get_index[ra_get_index]+0x0): multiple definition of `ra_get_index'
CMakeFiles\print_graphs.dir/objects.a(roaring.c.obj):roaring.c:(.text+0x65a1): first defined here
CMakeFiles\print_graphs.dir/objects.a(set_cover_solver.cpp.obj):set_cover_solver.cpp:(.text$ra_get_container_at_index[ra_get_container_at_index]+0x0): multiple definition of `ra_get_container_at_index'
CMakeFiles\print_graphs.dir/objects.a(roaring.c.obj):roaring.c:(.text+0x660e): first defined here
CMakeFiles\print_graphs.dir/objects.a(set_cover_solver.cpp.obj):set_cover_solver.cpp:(.text$roaring_bitmap_add_range[roaring_bitmap_add_range]+0x0): multiple definition of `roaring_bitmap_add_range'
CMakeFiles\print_graphs.dir/objects.a(roaring.c.obj):roaring.c:(.text+0x688e): first defined here
CMakeFiles\print_graphs.dir/objects.a(set_cover_solver.cpp.obj):set_cover_solver.cpp:(.text$roaring_bitmap_contains[roaring_bitmap_contains]+0x0): multiple definition of `roaring_bitmap_contains'
CMakeFiles\print_graphs.dir/objects.a(roaring.c.obj):roaring.c:(.text+0x690a): first defined here
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make[2]: *** [src\CMakeFiles\print_graphs.dir\build.make:104: src/print_graphs.exe] Error 1
mingw32-make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:933: src/CMakeFiles/print_graphs.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make: *** [Makefile:94: all] Error 2
```

In the CMakeLists.txt file in my src/ directory, I have the following basic code:

```
# Add header files:
set(HEADERS
    ${HEADERS_DIR}/cxxopts.h
    ${HEADERS_DIR}/roaring.h
    ${HEADERS_DIR}/roaring.hh
    ${HEADERS_DIR}/pugiconfig.h
    ${HEADERS_DIR}/pugixml.h
    ...
)

# Add object source files:
set(SOURCES 
    roaring.c
    pugixml.cpp
    ...
)

# Combine the object source files into an object library:
add_library(objects OBJECT ${SOURCES} ${HEADERS})

# Point the build targets to their include directories:
target_include_directories(objects PRIVATE ${HEADERS_DIR})

# Add all executable scripts to be generated:
add_executable(program1 $<TARGET_OBJECTS:objects> program1.cpp )

# Point the build targets to their include directories:
target_include_directories(program1 PRIVATE ${HEADERS_DIR})

# Make sure the build targets are compiled with C++11:
target_compile_features(program1 PRIVATE cxx_std_11)
```

I'm new to CMake, so I'm willing to bet that the issue is bad form on my part in the CMakeLists.txt file. But since CMake is able to build everything without problems when I use other generators, I'm not sure what the issue is. Does anyone know what might be causing the issue with the MinGW Makefiles generator in particular?

Comment: Shouldn't you use `target_link_libraries(program1 objects)` to link object files?

Comment: "I get a flood of multiple definition errors for methods ..." - Do not *describe* the errors message, **show** that error message instead. Also, you may pass `VERBOSE=1` option to `mingw32-make` for see actual command line used for linking. Check that this command line actually contains duplicate object files.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, thanks for the recommendation. I edited the post to include the error messages. I also ran `mingw32-make` with the `VERBOSE=1` option, and I got the following commands before the multiple definition errors:

Comment: `"C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E remove -f CMakeFiles\print_graphs.dir/objects.a`

`C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin\ar.exe cr CMakeFiles\print_graphs.dir/objects.a @CMakeFiles\print_graphs.dir\objects1.rsp`

`C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin\g++.exe    -Wl,--whole-archive CMakeFiles\print_graphs.dir/objects.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive  -o print_graphs.exe -Wl,--out-implib,libprint_graphs.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0 @CMakeFiles\print_graphs.dir\linklibs.rsp`

The only thing that strikes me is that the path to `ar` and `g++` is through chocolatey, not mingw.

Comment: As far as I can tell, there are no duplicate files appearing in the commands. `objects.a` gets built, and then it is referenced for linking.

Comment: Well, the error message is clear: You have **two source files** - `roaring.c` and `print_graphs.cpp` - which defines the **same functions**. Or it could be a *header* file which defines that functions. You need to find that multiple definition and fix it. Since you don't provide the code (which contains that definitions) we couldn't help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found the issue, and, as expected, it was bad form in CMake on my part. In the section of my code with

```
# Combine the object source files into an object library:
add_library(objects OBJECT ${SOURCES} ${HEADERS})
```

There was no need to reference `${HEADERS}`, as that connection is made explicitly in the next couple lines:

```
# Point the build targets to their include directories:
target_include_directories(objects PRIVATE ${HEADERS_DIR})
```

Including a reference to the header files in the initial `add_library` call seems to result in a duplication of the header files (or at least of references to them).

I'm still not sure why other build tools weren't tripped up by this issue while `mingw32-make` was, but proper syntax is good to maintain in any event, and things are working as expected now.